# How to extend vector size by one element and fill it with variable

Tags: c++, vector

I want to increase the size of a `vector` named `l_nMinplacesPos` by only one element and fill the new element by value from a variable named `m_nCurrentTime` (in preparation for sharing it by MPI function, `MPI_Bcast`, to other nodes).

I thought of `push_back()` and `resize()`, but I want to know if these are the only ways or if there is a better way?

I know this is wrong syntax, but I want to illustrate the idea:

```
void ParaStochSimulator::broad_casting(long j){
    std::cout << "i'm broad_casting" << std::endl;
    l_nMinplacesPos = (*m_pcTransitionsInfo)[j]->GetManipulatedPlaces();
    double m_nCurrentTime;
    l_anMarking.reserve(l_nMinplacesPos.size());

    //the vector that i want to extend:
    l_nMinplacesPos.resize( 1,m_nCurrentTime); //HERE
    MPI_Bcast(&l_anMarking, l_nMinplacesPos.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: You know about `push_back`, so use it. That's exactly what it's for. Don't mess with `reserve` without a reason. Your `resize` shrinks the vector down to one, wiping out whatever was there before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution if you want to use the [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) member function of the vector template class, is to do like this:

```
l_nMinplacesPos.resize(l_nMinplacesPos.size()+1, m_nCurrentTime);
```

Here you are indicating to **increase the size of the vector by only 1 element as you asked in your question**, i.e the current size + 1 : `l_nMinplacesPos.size()+1`

And in the same time you are telling the resize member function to **fill that element with the value: `m_nCurrentTime`**

Answer (score 4):

Use `vector.push_back(value);`.

In your case, this would be:

`l_nMinplacesPos.push_back(m_nCurrentTime);`